# AWS S3 Select CSV WHERE filtering not working on last column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I have a csv file in my s3 that looks like this

```
name,status,age,loc
aaa,aaa,1,zz
bbb,bbb,2,yy
ccc,,3,pp
ddd,ddd,4,aaa
```

`SELECT * FROM s3object s WHERE name ='aaa'`
This query returns first row correctly.

`SELECT * FROM s3object s WHERE loc ='aaa'`
This query does not return anything, but I expected it to return the last row.

Filtering on `status` also seems to work fine. Is there a reason why `SELECT * FROM s3object s WHERE loc ='aaa'` is not working?

Here's a screenshot of my settings

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce this. Looks like a bug to me

Comment: That's unfortunate. It seems it's a problem specifically on the last column. If you add another column, it starts working.

Comment: [It worked fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQM9k.png) -- I received an output of `ddd,ddd,4,aaa`. I did it with both LF and CRLF file formats. What happens if you try `WHERE loc like 'aaa%'`, in case there's a bad character at the end of the line?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein When I do like 'aaa%', it picks it up. But doing equal still fails. Very strange.  What could this mean? When I try to dl the file, it shows crlf

Comment: It worked for me with both LF and CRLF. Did you try saving it as just LF? How is the CSV file being generated?

Comment: I'm just opening up notepad++ on windows 10, saving it, and then uploading it to s3. When I convert it to LF, it seems to work just fine.